# How to merge two, three, x videos so that they will play side by side in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, video-capture, video-processing

I want to take x videos that all have the same length and merge them into a single side-by-side file. Meaning that at all times we will see all x videos playing side by side.

Extra info: Already using ReactRTC, wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Decide which video codec/format you want your file to be saved as, then search Google for such `javascript format-x encoder`. If none found, the only possibility is to write an encoder yourself. If PHP is an option then try to install an encoder like FFmpeg on your server. If you don't know FFmpeg then test out the desktop version first..

Comment: PS: My point was if you install a free encoder like FFmpeg then you could try using PHP's **std.In/Out** to generate video frames. Whilst paused video, you draw the 3 videos side by side in canvas. You grab the canvas bitmap data and **stdOut** (send) that to FFmpeg to encode as video frame, Seek to next frame of each video and repeat the snapshot + send to FFmpeg process until video ending...